# "Indexed" array function argument in C

Tags: c, arrays

I recently saw a function written in the following form `void func(int size, int a[size]){ ... }` and I was curious about the argument `a[size]`. At first I thought maybe it had something to do with indexing the array, but running the code `a` was in fact an array. Then I thought maybe it had to do with the size of the array, so I tried passing in different value and seeing if it would affect the array length, but it seemed not to (unless maybe it had something to do with writing past the array, but this feels unlikely). So my question is essentially, what does the "index" do in the function arguments?

Comment: @DavidRanieri It's not a VLA if it's a function parameter.

Comment: @Barmar well, it's a VLA used as function parameter, but it's a VLA, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidRanieri No, it's just equivalent to `int *a`. The size is ignored.

Comment: @Barmar you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the array size, but it's ignored when it's in a function parameter declaration. A function parameter of the form `int a[size]` or `int a[]` is treated identically to `int *a`, because arrays decay to pointers when used as function arguments.

So it's essentially just a form of self-documentation. The caller is supposed to pass an array that contains `size` elements.

Note that this only applies to the first dimension in a multidimensional array parameter. If you have something like

```
void func(int width, int height, int a[height][width]) { ... }
```

The `width` part of the array declaration is used, but the `height` is ignored. `a` is a pointer to an array of `int[width]` rows; the width is needed when indexing the first dimension.

Comment: You're right. I had the parameters in the wrong order.